# How to wall mount the Pi and its monitor?

Tags: case

**Question**

Is there a product which will help me wallmount my Pi? A simple DIY solution?

**Background**

I want to wall mount a Raspberry Pi and its monitor. I've seen lots of VESA mounts for mounting a raspi to the back of a screen but have not found anything for attaching the raspi to the monitor and then the whole assembly to a wall.

Answer (score 4):

The case that I purchased for my Pi has cross-shaped holes that can be easily used for mounting to a wall:

[SB Raspberry Pi Case (Clear) on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008TCUXLW)

[image]
[image]

This should work well for you if there is enough space between the back of your monitor and the wall to fit the Pi-case, so they would be mounted separately. If the space is limited, you can also use just one half of this case as a mount. The Pi firs this case snuggly, so it would quite stable. However, this answer does not address your question if you want to mount the Pi on the monitor. What particular setup would work depends on the monitor itself.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:288365

This is an interesting website. It shows an item that you can purchase. This item allows you to mount the raspberrypi (when in original container) to a wall or the back of a tv, or whatever else you choose to do

Answer (score 0):

Easily just as much as a Pi, the PiCano *can* do the trick, but I think I'd prefer a mount that consists of a plate covering the usual VESA area of mounts and extends out to the side of that for mounting the Pi.  The PiCano mounts to the TV/Monitor, and another VESA mount can attach to the PiCano.  I suppose it works, it just adds extra stress to the mounts (you know, the part that holds the TV in the air), and when putting up a big screen, that becomes a problem.  You can find the PiCano at:
http://picano.info

Comment: I suspect that you are affiliated with the picano - that should be made clear in your answer.